# How can i get hidden control id in parent page in the user control page using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can i get hidden control id in parent page in the user control page using javascript. there is a hidden input control in the page. i want to assign value to this control in the user control page which is used in this page. its an ascx page control.

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" name="isChanged" id="isChanged" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using jquery using the 'ends with' selector.

```
var element = $("input[id$=isChanged]")[0];
```

This assumes you only have one input on your page with an id which ends in 'isChanged'. The reason we use ends with is because asp will make the client side id of your control something like ct100$placeholder1$mypanel$isChanged.

A more robust solution would be to have a property on your usercontrol (eg 'ClientIdOfHiddenField') that you set from your parent page on page_load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1.ClientIdOfHiddenField = isChanged.ClientID;
}
```

then in the markup of your user control you can have

```
var element = document.getElementById("<%= ClientIdOfHiddenField %>");
```

Comment: your second method helped me to short out my problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Register like as below

```
isChanged.ClientID- is serverside property... so this will work for you 

document.getElementById("<%=isChanged.ClientID %>");
```

Comment: The control is in the parent page where the user control is called. so on page load itself it showing error page control not exist

Comment: Assuming I understand his question correctly, the hidden field is on a page, while he is trying to access the item from within a user control. If this is the case, 'isChanged' will not be visible.

Comment: @Geetha - he need to write script in user control only and expose that variable ...as javascript variable is global that varible is avaiable on the parent page easily...i hop you got now

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you should be able to use

```
var hidden = $('input[id$="isChanged"]');
```

otherwise @Pranay Rana's answer should work.